# Forcing Docker Desktop to use a particular host endpoint

Tags: linux, docker, fedora, docker-desktop

I'm running Docker Desktop on Fedora.  I cannot run some containers.  It seems that the Docker Endpoint in my context is being ignored.  My context shows

```
$ docker context list
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                    KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRA TOR
default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock
desktop-linux *     moby                Docker Desktop                            unix:///home/user123/.docker/desktop/docker.sock
```

When I try to run, Docker tries to connect to the wrong daemon

```
$ docker run testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.1
2023/06/19 20:29:00 Pinging Docker...
panic: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I also see the above in the logs if I try to run from the DD Dashboard.  Is there any way that I can force Docker to use the desktop-linux endpoint?

(Some things that I've tried:

- explicitly setting the DOCKER_HOST environment variable
- using --host and --context on the command line
- creating a symlink from /var/run/docker.sock to /home/user123/.docker/desktop/docker.sock)